# Looping over map and using a function on value (SCSS)

Tags: function, dictionary, sass

I have a map of text sizes, which I want to loop over and use a function on each value.

```
$textsizes: (
    '12'    : 12px,
    '14'    : 14px,
    '16'    : 16px,
);


@each $textSizeName, $textSizeUnit in $textsizes {
    .u-text-#{$textSizeName} {
        font-size: rem(#{$textSizeUnit});
    }
};
```

The function rem just turns the pixel value into a rem value. The function works as expected when used outside of the loop, but inside nothing happens, it just returns the px value.

I also tried to put the function in the maps value, like so:

```
$textsizes: (
    '12'    : rem(12px),
    '14'    : rem(14px),
    '16'    : rem(16px),
);
```

And then just output the value in the loop, however that will just return the value as a string, not the result of the function.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I go about this to get the result that I want?

Comment: Mmmh... Have you tried to write `rem($textSizeUnit)` without interpolation syntax?

Comment: Ah! I had not, I don't know why - but that works! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! :)